# Генерация контракта для ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net-web-api

Можно ли для WEB API сгенерировать конктракт-описание на манер, как это делает WCF?

Т.е список .NET типов и всяких методов.

Comment: Можно для WCF прописать до кучи web/rest endpoint. Возможно переход на wcf будет правильным решением, с этой точки зрения.

Comment: Можно использовать swagger. Ныне это, по сути, стандарт. [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-2.2), [2](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Swagger-integration-in-da408b29), [3](http://wmpratt.com/swagger-and-asp-net-web-api-part-1/), [4](https://aspnetcore.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger.html).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov и эта штука, как я понимаю, сама автоматически сгенерит "контракт" с описанием каждого API-метода?

Comment: Да. Причём ещё и красиво выглядящую html-страницу сверстает.